# Subtemplate Handlebars with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

I am working on a `nodejs` project using `handlebars` and `express3-handlebars` for templating and I need to be able to insert templates within another template. I am already using a master layout for the main template. An example of how I have it structured is as follows:

main.handlebars

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
{{{body}}}
</body>
</html>
```

page.handlebars

```
<h1>Test</h1>
{{{subtemplate}}}
```

rendering function:

```
function(req, res){
    res.render('page');
};
```

In the rendering function, I want to be able to pass in another handlebars template to be rendered where `{{{subtemplate}}}` is. Is there a way to do this using `handlebars` or do I need to switch to another templating engine?